# executing multiple mysql statements in a single session in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, commit

I have a large MySQL file that I need to execute statements from I also need to `SET autocommit=0` before and `COMMIT` after executing this MySQL file.

I don’t want to create or modify files.

Is there a way to execute all 3 of them in one or multiple lines in a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ echo "SET autocommit = 0;"
  cat filename.sql
  echo "commit;" ; } | mysql
```